# How can I get a user role history?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way to get a user role history? Let's say I added a new user with the role Subscriber. Now I manually updated the role to "Editor", and then "Administrator".

Is there any way to get the history of the user with date/time?

For e.g:
User 1 was a "Subscriber" on 25/01/2023
User 1 updated to "Editor" on 27/01/2023.
User 1 updated to "Administrator" on 29/01/2023.

I know we can fetch the current display role

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in core WordPress that records this history.  There are some popular history plugins you might try. https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/history/

The current role settings for each user are stored in `wp_usermeta` in an entry with `meta_key` = `'wp_capabilities'`.  For example, an editor will have this meta value:

```php
array( 'editor' => true )
```

Recording changes to those metadata values will give you the history if you decide to do this with your own plugin code. You can hook the `'update_user_meta'`, `'add_user_meta'`, and `'delete_user_meta'` actions to intercept changes.